# How do I place text to the right of a relatively positioned image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image that's relatively positioned so that I can do a css mouseover effect on it (when you mouseover it, it changes the image). It's a responsive design so the image can grow or shrink based on the screen size.

I want to display text immediately to the right of this image. Can anyone show me how to do that?

Here's my code now - the text ends up displaying behind (rather than beside) the image. Thanks!

**CSS** (changes image on mouse-over):

```
#mypic {
  position:relative;
  max-width:100%;
}

#mypic img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
}

#mypic img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="mypic"><img class="bottom" src="bottom.jpg" /><img class="top" src="top.jpg" /></div>
<p>Here is text that should be displayed to the right of the image.</p>
```

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute;` on the actual `img`?

Comment: This is the most simple way. https://jsfiddle.net/kvx28zv7/

Comment: For changing the `img` on `:hover`, go for an easier solution: Just apply the images as background-images.

Comment: @connexo - so that I can have both images in the same place and on hover, make the top one invisible and the bottom appears. But then verticle-align: middle doesn't work (or I couldn't figure out a way to make it work) with the relative position.

Comment: I didn't want to do background image because then (I believe) you have to hard code the width/height of the image and I need the image to be able to change size with the screen size. Also you get interesting transition options the css way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/a0my545L/1/

I set the width of the `<div>` to `400px;` then floated your text left with a margin left of `400px;`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I need that but without hard coding the image width (400px) because the image width will change based on screen size. There has to be a way to do this, right?

Comment: YES! Thank you thank you thank you! I did change #mypic max-width to 50% (instead of width 50%) and now it's perfect.